# Probability that a 2 was rolled, given an even number has been rolled

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've been learning conditional probability and encountered the problem statement given in the title. We roll the die only a single time:

My method of solving the question:

A: Event that the die rolled a 2

B: Event that the die rolled an even number

P(A) = 1/6

P(B) = 1/2

Then we have P(A|B) = P(A,B)/P(B) = (1/6)*(1/2)/(1/6) = 1/2. In some places, the answer was given as 1/3. Is this method correct? Also how can we find P(A,B) when we only have a single throw of a die.

Answer (score 2):

Had you not been provided with the knowledge that the die rolled an even number i.e. in case of simple probability, the probability of rolling 2 on single throw of die would have been $1/6$ as there are $6$ possible outcomes. But in this case of conditional probability, there are only three possible outcomes viz. $2,4,6$ once you are told that the die rolled an even number. This makes the required probability $1/3$.

Also the formula for conditional probability $ P(A/B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ gives $P(A/B)= (1/6)/(1/2)=1/3$ as the probability of rolling an even number is $1/2$.

My earlier answer had $P(A)$ in the numerator which was erroneous although that yielded the correct answer as $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$ were same.

Comment: Isn't the formula for conditional probability consisting of P(A AND B) as the numerator? When do we use that formula

Comment: @shawnin damnen $P(A/B)$ means the probability of occurrence of event $A$ given that event $B$ also took place. This has the effect of decreasing the number of possible outcomes and thus increasing the probability as compared to simple probability scenario. You can't use P(A&B) here as here events do not take place one after the other. These two events take place simultaneously.

Comment: @shawnin damnen We use P(A&B) in case of two independent events where the occurrence of one does not have any effect on the occurrence of the second event. E.g. in case of two throws of a die one after other. In the case at hand, both events are connected to the same principal event i.e. single throw of a die. Once you say that the die rolled an even number, numbers $1,3,5$ are precluded from getting rolled.